# How can I instantiate a lambda closure type in C++11/14?

Tags: c++, performance, lambda, closures, c++14

I'm [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708180/lambda-closure-type-constructors) that there's no default constructor for lambda closure type. But does that mean it's impossible to instantiate it after it being passed as a template parameter?

Consider the following [minimal example](https://ideone.com/QnPYL8):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename FuncType>
std::pair<int,int> DoSomething() {
    return FuncType()(std::make_pair(1,1));
}

int main() {
    auto myLambda = [](std::pair<int,int> x) {
        return std::make_pair(x.first*2,x.second*2);
    };
    std::pair<int,int> res = DoSomething<decltype(myLambda)>();
    return 0;
}
```

For performance reasons, [I can't use `std::function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction) to avoid virtual pointer calls. Is there a way to do this? I need to instantiate that lambda once and use it many times inside that function.

How does the standard library make it work when `decltype(myLambda)` is passed to something like `std::map` comparators in the template parameter?

Comment: A lambda is mostly just syntactic sugar for an anonymous class with an `operator()`. Declare your own, named class, with your own `operator()` that implements your lambda.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm hoping I won't have to restrict the user from using lambdas. I would like it to be just like the standard library example I mentioned.

Comment: I don't know what "user" means. This [now looks to be like a definite XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe you should try asking what your real question is. No, not the one that you wrote here, but the real question to which you believe the answer is to use lambdas this way, and that's what you're asking about. Maybe there's a completely different solution to your real question, but without knowing what it is, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I think that you are looking for [this talk by Louis Dionne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTb6xz_FSkY), the author of [the paper that later proposed adding default constructors to stateless clousure types](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0624r2.pdf).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't believe this is an XY problem. Let me try to clarify, maybe that helps. A user will call some function in my library (`DoSomething` in this case). The function has to take another function as a parameter (whether template or otherwise), just like I showed up there. The user doesn't have to bother with my internal implementation of `DoSomething`, but I know that my implementation will call that (templatized) function quite often, because of the algorithm I'm using. So, my implementation shouldn't restrict the user to use a lambda or a named functor.

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I'll watch that now.

Comment: I feel like I don't understand something here. Why not pass the lambda as a function parameter and call that many times?

Comment: @NikosC. What will the parameter type be?

Comment: The parameter type will be what it is now, only deduced from the argument.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, the standard library [cannot make it work for std::map and the like](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hg35mxfOJH7I7pqN) before c++20

Comment: @Mike Weird... I remember doing this very often. Last time I did it was in `std::unique_ptr` deleter.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Is there some reason why it *must* be spelled `auto myLambda = [](std::pair<int,int> x){...};` instead of `struct MyLambda { auto operator(std::pair<int, int> x){...};};`? At the end of the day, it's not *that* much longer...

Comment: @NicolBolas Just for user convenience.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: But the `struct` version is just as convenient. Not only does it work pre-C++20, it also doesn't require `decltype` gymnastics. I can understand wanting to use a lambda if capturing is involved (since capturing through constructors is a huge pain), but once you take captures off the table, what's the point?

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not the one who will call that function. A user of that library would. I don't want to restrict users' options in the way they do the calls. If it were up to me in my internal program, I'd agree with you 100%. The solutions down there with passing lambdas' objects are reasonable and are a good compromise. For some reason it didn't occur to me to do that from the beginning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this feature is coming in C++20 (see songyuanyao's answer), you don't actually need that in this case. You can just pass the lambda as a function parameter of type `FuncType` and call that multiple times:

```
template <typename FuncType>
std::pair<int,int> DoSomething(FuncType f)
{
    return f(std::make_pair(1,1));
}

int main()
{
    auto myLambda = [](std::pair<int,int> x) {
        return std::make_pair(x.first*2,x.second*2);
    };
    std::pair<int,int> res = DoSomething(myLambda);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> I'm aware that there's no default constructor for lambda closure type.

Yes, this is true until C++20. (Note that since C++20 if no captures are specified, the [closure type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) has a defaulted default constructor.)

> Closure types are not DefaultConstructible. Closure types have `a deleted (until C++14)` `no (since C++14)` default constructor.  (until C++20)

And

> How does the standard library make it work when `decltype(myLambda)` is passed to something like `std::map` comparators in the template parameter?

There's nothing special for the standard library. If you specify a non-DefaultConstructible lambda as the comparator type for `std::map`, you have to pass an object to the constructor, `std::map` will initialized its comparator via copy; lambda has copy and move constructor.

You can change your code to the same way as [`std::map`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map):

```
template <typename FuncType>
std::pair<int,int> DoSomething(const FuncType& f = FuncType()) {
    // auto z(f);   // you can take a copy if necessary
    return f(std::make_pair(1,1));
}
```

then

```
auto myLambda = [](std::pair<int,int> x) {
    return std::make_pair(x.first*2,x.second*2);
};
std::pair<int,int> res = DoSomething<decltype(myLambda)>(myLambda);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FTSLTgKBVE9uDBLK)

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, empty lambdas will become default-constructible in C++20.

You cannot wait for / switch to it?
No problem, it's easily emulated, as long as your lambda isn't generic.

Simply convert the lambda to a function-pointer, and pack that into a `std::integral_constant`:

```
template <class T>
constexpr auto make_constant(T t) noexcept
-> std::integral_constant<decltype(+t), +t>
{ return {}; }
```

Of course, in most cases where you can choose a function-objects type, you can also pass the initial value, which is a bit easier.