# Why is Vector used as a second argument to Priority Queue?

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, priority-queue, decltype

Why is it that when priority_queue is used with a single data type, like 'int', we initialise it like this: `priority_queue<int>`; but, when it's initialized with a pair we add a second parameter of type vector `priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>>`?

Also, I've noticed several ways to add a third argument that specifies ordering.

**Method 1** - Struct

```
struct myCompare {
   bool operator()(const pair<int, int>& A, const pair<int, int>& B) {
       return A.second < B.second;
   }
};

priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, myCompare> leaderBoard;
```

**Method 2** - Lambda

```
auto myComp = [](const pair<int, int>& A, const pair<int, int>& B) 
              {return A.second < B.second;};

priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(myComp)> leaderBoard(myComp);
```

**My Questions**

1. Why is the second parameter of `priority_queue` a `vector`? What does this mean and when does this second parameter need to be specified?
2. In method 2, why is `decltype` needed with this lambda?
3. In method 2, why does the object `leaderBoard` need to be initialised with `(myComp)`
4. In method 2, why can I not specify my lambda as the third argument directly?
5. What is the difference between `A.second > B.second` and `A.second < B.second`? How do you remember which one means ascending order, and which one is descending order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is it that when `priority_queue` is used with a single data type, like 'int', we initialise it like this: `priority_queue<int>` [...] ?

Because `std::priority_queue` is a class template defined as follows:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

As you can see, you can instantiate this class only providing the `T`, because the rest of the types will be defaulted. You can read more about [template default arguments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373823/template-default-arguments).

> but, when it's initialized with a pair we add a second parameter of type vector `priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>>`?

Because someone wanted to be explicit. `priority_queue<pair<int, int>>` is equivalent to `priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>>`, because the second template type (`vector<pair<int, int>>`) will be present by default.

> 1. Why is the second parameter of priority_queue a vector? What does this mean and when does this second parameter need to be specified?

We don't need to specify it **explicitly**. The second template parameter is a type use for internal representation of data. `std::priority_queue` is a *container adaptor*, which means that it's not a container by itself - it uses some other container and *wraps* it with certain kind of utilities.

> 2. In method 2, why is decltype needed with this lambda?

Because you need to provide a *type*. `myCompare` is a `struct`, so it's a name of a type. `myComp` is not a type, it's a variable. You wish to get its *declared type*? Use `decltype`.

> 3. In method 2, why does the object leaderBoard need to be initialised with `(myComp)`?

Because you cannot default construct an object given a `decltype` of a lambda ([this got relaxed in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708180/lambda-closure-type-constructors)). You need to use the following constructor:

```
explicit priority_queue(const Compare& compare)
    : priority_queue(compare, Container()) { }
```

which expects a callable (in this case - the lambda) that will be used as a comparator.

> 4. In method 2, why can I not specify my lambda as the third argument directly?

You mean as the third `template` argument? Because as of right now, lambdas cannot be used in unevaluated contexts, and providing a type for a template is one of those.

> 5.1. What is the difference between `A.second > B.second` and `A.second < B.second`?

The difference is quite blatant. One checks for `A.second` being greater than the second argument and the other one is the reverse. It is commonly used for sorting (for comparing elements).

> 5.2 How do you remember which one means ascending order, and which one is descending order?

It's pretty easy - the `C++` conception is to use `<` between the ***left** hand side* argument and the ***right** hand side* argument, like so: `left_hand_side < right_hand_side`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but for 5.2 I meant:
If we have a list of `1 2 4 1 2 51 5 3 1 2`, how do I know if `return A < B` will put them in ascending or descending order. As I understand, B is the second element, and A is the first element, so it's saying that B must be bigger than A, hence ascending?

Comment: @TomerTzadok correct. Sorting algorithms require a comparator callable which, given two arbitrary elements, will represent a *strict, weak ordering*, i.e. `<` relation. They sort *ascending* in regard to the `<` relation. Sorting descending, for example, is simply *sorting ascending, but with `>` relation*.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the second parameter of priority_queue a vector?

You can use any container that satisfies [certain requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). `vector` is a reasonable default choice.

> What does this mean and when does this second parameter need to be specified?

If either you want to change its default value, or you want to specify the third one. `std::priority_queue<std::pair<int,int>>` is a valid type without specifying the second paramater.

> In method 2, why is decltype needed with this lambda?

If you want to use a custom comparator, you have to specify its type as a third template parameter. Each lambda has its own unique type, the only way to obtain it, is through `decltype`.

> In method 2, why does the object leaderBoard need to be initialised with (myComp)

Because `struct`-based comparator can be default constructed, but lambda-based one can't. The relevant constructors are

```
priority_queue() : priority_queue(Compare(), Container()) { }
priority_queue(const Compare& compare) : priority_queue(compare, Container()) { }
```

If you don't provide `compare`, `Compare()` is used. `myCompare()` is a valid value, and `decltype(myComp)()` is not.

> In method 2, why can I not specify my lambda as the third argument directly?

You need a type, not a value of that type.

> What is the difference between A.second > B.second and A.second < B.second?

Swapping the order of arguments (or, equivalently, `<` and `>`) turns a min-heap into a max-heap and vice versa, i.e. that order determines which element will be returned by `.top()`, the smallest or the largest.

Comment: `In method 2, why can I not specify my lambda as the third argument directly?`
I mean, why can I not replace `decltype(myComp)` with the lambda expression `[](const pair<int, int>& A, const pair<int, int>& B) 
              {return A.second < B.second;};` like I would in any other STL algorithm? I guess it's because this is an object being constructed, and not an algorithm.

I also don't understand where `decltype(myComp)` fits into the priority_queue constructor. Mind elaborating a little please?

Comment: @TomerTzadok Until C++20, The language did not allow you to declare a lambda in a template.

Comment: @TomerTzadok, `[](...) {...}` is a value, not a type. You need a type there.

Answer (score 1):

> In method 2, why does the object leaderBoard need to be initialised
>   with (myComp)

it depends on what C++ standard you use. Before C++20 you need to pass functor created by lambda expression to `priority_queue` constructor because lambdas until C++20 were not default constructible.

Since C++20 you can write:

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(myComp)> leaderBoard;
```

it will work fine because compiler knows type of lambda - specified by `decltype(myComp)`, and it can call its default ctor.

---

> In method 2, why can I not specify my lambda as the third argument
>   directly?

Yes, you can but you need to still use `decltype` to get comparator type:

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, 
     decltype( [](const pair<int, int>& A, const pair<int, int>& B) 
              {return A.second < B.second;} ) > leaderBoard;
```

Comment: IIRC, we cannot use a lambda in an unevaluated context, such as inside `decltype`.

Comment: @DanielLangr As per [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0315r4.pdf) it is allowed. I tested the code above with `c++2a` under G++, compiles and works fine.